# Node js reaching memory limits from external requests

Tags: node.js, request, heap-memory

I'm running the following code on a server where I'm trying to build a realtime dashboard. I'm pulling data from an API source and I need to post it to clients every once in a while. Right now I'm trying to figure out what my server can handle and I've found that after running this code for about twenty minutes, the server slows down and crashes without displaying an error message. I suspect that it's because I keep making more and more asynchronous requests (300 every 5 seconds) and that I'm eating up the memory by piling on more requests before the previous ones have been able to resolve.

```
var request = require('request');

var async = require('async');
var db = require('./db.js');
var _ = require('underscore');

var urls = [...]; // List of ~300 urls, 

var interval = setInterval(runRequests, 5000);

function runRequests() {
    var requests = [];

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            var query = 'select apitoken from apidata where id = 1';
            db.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                if (rows) {
                    return callback(null, rows[0]['apitoken'];
                }
             });
         },
         function(token, callback) {
             _.each(urls, function(url) {
                 var req = request({
                     url: url,
                     method: "GET",
                     headers: {
                         authorization: token
                     }
                  }, function(err, res, body) {
                     var json = parseJsonSafely(body);

                     if(json) {
                          // Emitting logic
                     }
                     // If the token has expired, shutdown the rest of the
                     // ongoing request that are bound to fail
                     else if(body === 'Request is not authenticated.') {
                         _.each(requests, openRequest) {
                             openRequest.abort();
                         });
                         requests = [];

                         // ... code to refresh the api token
                     }
                  });

                  requests.push(req);
             });

             return calbackk(null);
         }
   ]);
}

function parseJsonSafely(json) {
    var parsedString;

    try {
        parsedString = JSON.parse(json);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('ERROR: JSON parsing failed. Input: ', json);
    }

    return parsedString;
}
```

When the code actually goes out to production, I'm only going to have to run the request at about every minute rather than every 5 seconds, but I'm currently trying to figure out what will happen as the number of urls I have to access grows.

Are there any countermeasures I can take from preventing the code from eating up too much memory? One option I'm thinking of is adding a timeout to each request so that it expires automatically on its own, but I don't think this will make an impact if the requests are still waiting to fire when another round of requests are initiated. Another thing I could do is build a hash that ties each
request object to its corresponding url. Then when a new round of requests to the same url is initiated, I can just ignore the request for a particular url if it has not completed yet, and only make a new request if has been completed:

```
var hash = {};
var urls = [...];
_.each(urls, function(url) {
    if (!hash[url]) {
        hash[url] = result(..., function(err, res, body) {
            delete hash[url];
        });
    }
});
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that I don't think the request objects would ever get duplicated, so I would have to worry about the server's memory being eaten up.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to tackle this issue, I'd appreciate the it.

Comment: Have you looked into a solution like [socket.io](http://socket.io/)? Event-driven broadcasts ensure real-time updates, and a constant connection might be more performant than a bunch of intervals.

Comment: @colonelsanders, I am using socket.io. I'm using it to emit the results of the url requests off to the users who login to the app. However, I can't use user events because the point of the application is to push data from the company owning the API  to the clients who use my system. The company is logging data from a bunch of different machines and I'm making that data visible to end users.